How can I print the body of an exception while using a Spring Boot WebClient
I am invoking an API which returns the following output while invoking via a tool like Postman.
Error Code: 409 CONFLICT
Error Payload
{
    "error": {
        "code": 20054,
        "message": "The display name 'pr-test' is already used by another subaccount or directory under the parent of this entity. Display names of account entities under the same parent must be unique.",
        "target": "/accounts/v1/subaccounts",
        "correlationID": "7c8e0376-6d36-4038-45ea-9de453f732ef"
    }
}

What I am looking at is to access this payload, extract the error.message and throw a custom error.
My Webclient code looks like this:
          webClient.post()
              .uri(accountsSvcUrl)
              .bodyValue(createConsumerSubAccountPayload())
              .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer "+ credentialManager.getOauthToken(credentialManager.CLOUD_MANAGEMENT_CENTRAL))
              .retrieve()
              .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError,
                  error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException
                      ("Error while invoking the API Code: "+error.statusCode()+ " ")))
              .bodyToMono(SubAccountResponse.class)
              .block();

I want some help in understanding how can I get the error body under the onStatus block.
Sincerely appreciate your advice.
Prabal
